# printing path name in browser for a spring framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, spring

I am integrating my js with html..
the back end is spring frame work...
i dont have knowledege abt spring frame work...
i am trying to print the path name path="xxcpdEprBehavior.name"in browser...
providing my code below...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p>Click me away!</p>
<p>Click me too!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any reason why you are not using php for this purpose?

Comment: @Vector: they already wrote code in spring

Comment: is createBehavior contain xxcpdEprBehavior ? and xxcpdEprBehavior also contain a name ?